# Auto Import many .txt files into sql server table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have many *.txt* files and I want to import them into SQL Server table.

The file names are something like:

*hazem.20160922.txt*

*hazem2.20160921.txt*

The table exists already so no need to create it again. This is a daily activity, so I will need to automate that. I read many articles online and I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it is an automatic process that should happen every day, you can create an SSIS (ETL) Job to do this and you can schedule the job in such a away that it will run everyday.

Here is the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/818083/SSIS-Import-Text-File) that will clearly explain how to create an ETL package as Flat File source and Database Destination.

This [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/220/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/) will help you with step by step procedure for Scheduling a Job in SQL Server Agent.

You can select the folder path instead of file name in the Source so that ETL Job will move all the files in the folder to destination table once per day.

Answer (score -1):

using foreach loop in cursor

```
 declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE like '%.txt%'
    open c1
    fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
    While @@fetch_status <> -1
      begin
      --bulk insert won`enter code here`'t take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
       set @sql = 'BULK INSERT Temp FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
           + '     WITH ( 
                   FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
                   ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
                   FIRSTROW = 2 
                ) '
print @sql
exec (@sql)

  fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
  end
close c1
deallocate c1`enter code here`
```

Comment: i can only help

Comment: @BhaveshVaja But you're not helping.